# Patching a file without temporary diff file

Tags: bash, diff, patch

I am trying to revert a file from a previous version of the same file, using diff and patch

```
diff_out=$(diff -u $name $chVer/$name.latest)
patch -u $name $diff_out
```

Where $name is the file name i want to revert, $chVer is the folder of all the older versions of the file

Unfortunately this doesn't work

```
patch: unrecognized option '---'
patch: Try 'patch --help' for more information.
```

the $diff_out content is not read by the patch command as a file, thus do i need the output the content of the diff to a temporary file that i read with patch ? I wanted not to do that, because i will delete that file as soon as the patch is done

Comment: Why not just copy the old file over?

Comment: Quote your parameter expansions, and see if you still have a problem.

Comment: `cat $chVer/$name.latest > $name`

Answer (score 1):

Try `$diff_out | patch -u $name`

`patch` will accept a diff from `stdin` if not provided as an argument.

Comment: This answers the question of "how to patch a file with a temporary diff file". If the answer should be improved or is incorrect, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the temporary file by using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```bash
patch -u $name <(diff -u $name $chVer/$name.latest)
```